# How i send Qtableview inserted row as json?

Tags: pyqt5

i am new in pyqt5 and i am face to a problem of using QAbstractTableModel
i will present for you my Model and My question is how i send Qtableview  inserted row  from QAbstractTableModel as JSON?

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtCore import  Qt, QAbstractTableModel

    class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):     
    def __init__(self, dataIn,parent=None, *args): 
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.datatable = dataIn

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable) 

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if len(self.datatable) > 0:
            return len(self.datatable[0])
        else:
            return 0

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            i = index.row()
            j = index.column()
            return '{}'.format(list(self.datatable[i].values())[j]) if list(self.datatable[i].values())[j] else ''

    def setData(self, index, value , role=Qt.EditRole):
        i = index.row()
        j = index.column()
        self.datatable[i][list(self.datatable[i])[j]]=value
        return True
    
    def flags(self, index):
        if index.column() > 0:
            return Qt.ItemIsEditable  | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        else: 
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if (orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role==Qt.DisplayRole):
            return self.labels[section]
        else:
            return super().headerData(section, orientation, role=role)

    def insertRows(self, position, rows=1, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertRows(index, position, position + rows - 1)
        for i in range(position,position+rows):
            self.datatable.append({})
            for j in list(self.datatable[i-1]):
                self.datatable[i][j]=''
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    class InstrumentModel(MetrologieModel):
    def __init__(self, dataIn):
        super(InstrumentModel,self).__init__(dataIn)
        self.labels = ["Id","Code instrument","Name"]
```

i am blocked in this step and i need a help
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "send"? Send where and for what purpose?

Comment: i show data stored in database in QtableView by QAbstractTableModel and i Isucceeded to insert new row ... then i want now store this new inserted row to database as json data by using the SetData of QAbstractTableModel , do you understand me?

Comment: What kind of database is it? What ***specific*** data from the row are you trying to store, and what exactly is stopping you from converting it to json? Also: why aren't you using [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html)?

Comment: is potgres database and i save in it with urllib as request so no spécifique data is declared in Mymodel the code that i share it in my question ... i need the method to use Setdata() of my model and send data in urllib as json ....